# How to avoid having so many mongoose search conditionals?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

In my router for a post request, I parse the search parameters and then use a db find using the parameters. However, the user can choose to mix and match which parameters (title/tags) he wants to use/doesn't want to use, so it ends up that I have to search for a couple different things, thus there's a couple conditionals which determine the search as shown below.

```
router.post('/eventItems/:title', function(req, res) {
  psuedocode for setting up booleans
```

HERE IS WHERE MULTIPLE CONDITIONALS ARE USED TO DETERMINE WHICH SEARCH

```
if (tagsShouldBeSearched && searchTitle)
  {
    eventItem.find({title: searchTitle, tags: tags}, function(err, data) {
      var jsondata = JSON.stringify(data);
      res.render('eventItems', {events : jsondata, loggedIn: isLoggedIn,  matching_events: data, user : req.user });
    });
  }
  else if (tagsShouldBeSearched)
  {
    eventItem.find({tags: tags}, function(err, data) {
      var jsondata = JSON.stringify(data);
      res.render('eventItems', {events : jsondata, loggedIn: isLoggedIn,  matching_events: data, user : req.user });
    });
  }
  else
  {
    eventItem.find({title: searchTitle}, function(err, data) {
      var jsondata = JSON.stringify(data);
      res.render('eventItems', {events : jsondata, loggedIn: isLoggedIn,  matching_events: data, user : req.user });
    });
  }

});
```

Is there a better way to go about doing so without using so many conditionals? I also thought of using a lost of different router addresses for posting, but maybe that's too much?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build your query up using Mongoose's [where](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.where)

```
var Query = eventItem.find();

if (tagsShouldBeSearched) Query.where({tags: tags});
if (titleShouldBeSearched) Query.where({title: searchTitle});

Query.exec(function(err, data) {
  var jsondata = JSON.stringify(data);
  res.render('eventItems', {events : jsondata, loggedIn: isLoggedIn,  matching_events: data, user : req.user });
});
```